# Verify VTx Virtualization on XP

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Lenovo SL400 with a 2gHz Intel Core2 Duo P7370,the Intel specs show it may  or may not have VTx installed. The BIOS do not show Virtualization on the BIOS Set Up page. Question how can I check to see if it has it, what command can I use to 
verify this. I need this in order to use Virtual Box osis, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) which will tell you if your chip support virtualization extensions and if it is enabled.

Comment: Thank, I checked Securable last Saturday and stated "hardware virtualization was locked off" do you have any suggestions on correcting this, Thanks.  This

Comment: I found Intel Virtualization Tech {disabled} under CONFIG along with a note: a full reset is required to change the setting which sounds pretty risky to do.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "Security" tab in the BIOS and then you should see "Virtualization" and then "Intel Virtualization Technology" that's the one you need to enable.

Comment: Thanks, I found Intel Virtualization Tech {disabled] under CONFIG  along with a note: a full reset is required to change the setting, which in checking sounds pretty  risky.